# Remove cyclic close-votes

Tags: discussion, bug, vote-to-close, review-audits

Situation:

Question A have close vote "duplicate of B"
Question B has closed as duplicate of A.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2522617) (I seen 1 more before it)

It's at least strange. What will happen if it will closed?

Comment: If it makes a difference I voted to close the question in the example before the other one was closed.

Comment: Technically it doesn't have a close vote, it has a flag. It still needs 5 votes.

Comment: I often see a question that is closed as a duplicate of another question, which is also closed (and sometimes that one has been closed as a duplicate of yet another one that is also closed). I'm not sure it really matters if this is cyclic or not; the main problem is that it takes the user many more clicks to find the real answer. I wish we could do a better job of merging questions.

Comment: In my opinion, the +2 one with a +8 answer should've been closed a duplicate of the +50 one with a +34 answer (and others) (as in the other way around), regardless of age.

Comment: @apaul34208, is it possible to make it uncompleted then?

Comment: I've cast a vote on A for being a duplicate of B ;)

Comment: @Dukeling Done.